# How do i open one project's main window as an startup interface to other project?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image]

I was working on a project where I want to give an interface to the existing project(which initially doesn't have one). So I created another WPF project and created an interface main window with a button, when clicked it has to launch the second window (that is the application)

[image]

[image]

How should I define or give a reference between the two projects?

Comment: By project. You mean this is two solutions, two exe?  Why is this separate?

Comment: Hi @Andy I tried adding a new item(that is WPF) in the main project but couldn't find any WPF item, so I tried working the interface on by adding a new project, and now am not able to reference this newly created project main window to the existing project.

(And since am a newbie I watched many youtube stuff but still didn't get through)

Comment: Not sure you followed my question. Why is all your stuff not in just the one project?

Comment: @Andy Yes, these are two different .exe. Because I didn't find an option to add one more WPF window in my main project. Hence I created the interface in a different WPF project, now I want this to be a startup window, then when we click the "Launch" button it should pop-up the second project, which is the main application.